# Most efficient way to subtract arrays of unsigned chars in C

Tags: c, libpcap

I'm using libpcap to analyze and process packets. I have to compare two arrays of unsigned chars, take the difference and save it to a hashtable. Another thread will periodically scans across the hashtable and compute for average,standard deviation, max and min.

My question is the following, what would be the most efficient way to perform subtraction on two arrays?

For example:

```
A="0x34 0x44 0x59 0x5B"
B="0x34 0x42 0x43 0x43"
```

My first thought is to convert it to an integer, by converting the array into an array of signed chars, doing take requires a function to perform lookup function. Because this is function is called for every packet received on the system.

Comment: Why are you storing the values in a hash table if what you want to do with them is to compute average, standard deviation, max and min?  For none of these operations will a hash table be the most efficient data structure.  A contiguous array will be much better.

Comment: How about converting both packet's data to sets and using http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/

Comment: Not quite sure I follow. Are these long arrays? Or fixed length? Are you wanting to subtract the individual bytes or reinterpret the bytes as a longer integer?

Comment: The reason for a hash table is also because I need to key on certain patterns, and there is an array associated with each key. But you are right, if the pattern variations arenlow, I can use a n x m array, it will be much faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `union` can make this simple, because different data types share the same memory, we can then use this feature to convert data type.

note the [Little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian)

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union new_array{
    struct array {
        unsigned char f4;
        unsigned char f3;
        unsigned char f2;
        unsigned char f1;
    }array;
    unsigned int int_array;
}new_array;

int main()
{
    new_array A, B;
    A.array.f1 = 0x34;
    A.array.f2 = 0x44;
    A.array.f3 = 0x59;
    A.array.f4 = 0x5B;

    B.array.f1 = 0x34;
    B.array.f2 = 0x42;
    B.array.f3 = 0x43;
    B.array.f4 = 0x43;

    printf("%u\n", A.int_array - B.int_array);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, this is definitely much simpler than a lookup array!

Comment: I don't know of a compiler where this wouldn't work but isn't it undefined behavior as far as the standard is concerned?

Comment: I am not sure about what the standard says about this, but I use this trick successfully running many programs so far. @5gon12eder